# Ep. V - alternate opening crawl on Hoth

Tags: star-wars, behind-the-scenes, the-empire-strikes-back, hoth

From [StarWars.com - STAR WARS: EPISODE V THE EMPIRE STRIKES BACK - OPENING CRAWL](http://www.starwars.com/video/star-wars-episode-v-the-empire-strikes-back-opening-crawl):

> In an early form, the film's opening had the crawl appear not against space, but rather against the white snowy background of Hoth.

**o.O**

Is there any still or video of this alternate opening crawl? I'd be very interested in is seeing the crawl over Hoth's snowy wasteland.

Answer (score 1):

From [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NdXzAcwyVrY) YouTube reconstruction, it seems the crawl was never actually rendered against Hoth as a background. Instead, the "early form" talked about is simply a preliminary script that vaguely describes the opening crawl as

> *From what is believed to be the 3rd Draft*
>
> 1. EXT. PLAIN OF HOTH - HELICOPTER SHOT - DAY.
>
> A white snowscape races toward the camera ... the MAIN TITLE quickly recedes, followed by a roll-up.
> ...
> The roll-up disappears into the bleak horizon.
>
> 2. EXT. PLAIN OF HOTH - HELICOPTER SHOT - DAY.
>
> The camera tilts down bringing into view a small figure galloping across the windswept ice slope.